# Templates Calling Each Other's Functions

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I have a fairly simple set of templates that I want to use together, but the compiler keeps telling me that B::a has incomplete type. Everything is forward declared, but it still doesn't work...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class A;
template <typename T> class B;

template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    void ATestFunction();
    void CallBFunction();
protected:
    B<T> b;
};

template <typename T>
class B{
public:
    void BTestFunction();
    void CallAFunction();

protected:
    A<T> a;
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::ATestFunction(){
    cout << "A was used for a function call" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void B<T>::BTestFunction(){
    cout << "B was used for a function call" << endl;
}


template <typename T>
void A<T>::CallBFunction(){
    b.BTestFunction();
}

template <typename T>
void B<T>::CallAFunction(){
    a.ATestFunction();
}

int main()
{
    A<int> dragons;
    dragons.CallBFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

I ask this because I had run into some difficulty programming some array type classes that depend on each other (implementing a two dimensional array that can be accessed like this: [][]), but this problem happened and threw a gear in the works. I made this testing program, but it still fails. I've tried both MinGW 4.7.2 and GNU g++ on Linux, and each gave me the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

The core of the issue can be seen in this piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
    B<T> b;
};

template <typename T>
class B{
    A<T> a;
};
```

C++ is a language with value semantics, that means that `B<T> b;` represents an object of type `B<T>` (rather than a reference, like in Java or C# with reference types). That is, `A<T>` *contains* a `B<T>`. Now if you look at the definition of the `B` template you see that in turn it contains an `A<T>` sub object. This is basically impossible, as `A<T>` cannot possibly contain an object that contains `A<T>`. What would be the size of an `A<T>` object?

Without knowing the real problem to solve, I won't venture to recommend an approach, but you can consider using pointers (`A<T>` would contain a *pointer* to `B<T>`, not a full `B<T>` sub object; or similarly, `B<T>` could contain a *pointer* to `A<T>`; or both), or references. But it might also be the case that a deeper redesign could make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you used pointers, that could not work. That would basically trigger an infinite loop of A´s and B´s being created

A creates B creates A creates B creates A...

this would work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T> class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        b = new B<T>(this);
    }
    A(B<T>* pb)
    {
        b = pb;
    }
    void ATestFunction()
    {
        cout << "A was used for a function call" << endl;
    }
    void CallBFunction()
    {
        b->BTestFunction();
    }
protected:
    B<T>* b;
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        a = new A<T>(this);
    }
    B(A<T>* pa)
    {
        a = pa;
    }
    void BTestFunction()
    {
        cout << "B was used for a function call" << endl;
    }
    void CallAFunction()
    {
        a->ATestFunction();
    }

protected:
    A<T>* a;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> dragons;
    dragons.CallBFunction();

    B<int> bdragons;
    bdragons.CallAFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

or maybe just using static functions

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T> class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static void ATestFunction()
    {
        cout << "A was used for a function call" << endl;
    }
    void CallBFunction();

};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    static void BTestFunction()
    {
        cout << "B was used for a function call" << endl;
    }
    void CallAFunction();

};
template<typename T>
void A<T>::CallBFunction()
{
    B<int>::BTestFunction();
}


template<typename T>
void B<T>::CallAFunction()
{
    A<int>::ATestFunction();
}

int main()
{
    A<int> dragons;
    dragons.CallBFunction();

    B<int> bdragons;
    bdragons.CallAFunction();
    return 0;
}
```